# convert a sql statement to linq to entity vb.net

Tags: .net, linq

I am trying to convert the following sql statement into linq to entitys vb.net.  I have googled to no avail.  The sql removes duplicate residentkey records bringing back the top residentkey with the later version No.

```
      SELECT * FROM   dbo.BI_Bond z
     WHERE z.id IN (SELECT TOP 1 x.id FROM dbo.BI_Bond x 
WHERE x.residentkey = z.residentkey ORDER BY Version DESC )
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this.

```
var res = from b from BI_Bond
          where BI_Bond.Select(i => i.residentkey).Contains(b.residentkey).OrderByDesc(i.Version)
          select b;
```

I haven't compiled this but i believe its close.

cheers on being my first SO answer

Comment: thanks for the response, tried to translate this to vb.net but don't know the comparisons. I took another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim mv = From c In BI_Bond Group By c.residentKey Into version=Max(c.version)
Dim u = From a In BI_Bond Join b In mv On a.residentKey Equals b.residentKey And a.version Equals b.version Select a
```

This is returning the latest versioned row for each residentKey.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that did the trick.  When you write it like that it looks very simple. I am new to linq so this merging is a new concept to me.  In your experience where would suggest the best site be to go to to learn linq to entities. C# and vb.net

Comment: Sorry, self learner here: I just understood where MS was coming from, especially given that it is based upon SQL. That and just trying stuff.